# Automate infinitely scrolling webpage using selenium web driver in Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, infinite-scroll

I am trying to automate a webpage, where I need to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page and click on footer. However, the webpage i am automating has infinite scroll. Any help on this?

```
    public class practiceNG
    {
        WebDriver driver;
        @BeforeTest
        public void start()
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Y:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        }

        @Test (priority = 3)
        public void infiniteScroll() throws InterruptedException
        {
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", ""); 
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id=\'content\']/ul/li[23]/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"page-footer\"]/div/div/a")).click();
        }

        @AfterTest
        public void close()
        {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). What is the problem? What isn't working? Don't assume that people are going to take the time to run your code. Explain in detail what your code is attempting to do and what is going wrong... error messages or what exactly isn't working is needed here.

Comment: @JeffC I included what I have done. "I need to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page and click on footer" this is what I am trying to do and I mentioned it, also produced the code which failed me. I am not just asking for help without working on it. The 5 lines of code I produced is what is not working, out of my 283 lines of code. I also specified in my comment below, that the webpage scrolls down to some extent and then stops scrolling. So I don't think I am just seeking help without actually working on it.

Comment: @JeffC Also, I have gone through several other similar questions posted on Stack Overflow. Only after trying all the possible solutions, I posted this question.

Comment: Where is your code where you scroll more than once? You state that you tried other methods but you didn't list or link to any other methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
    while(footerIsNotPresent()){
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
        }
```

You can replace footerIsNotPresent() with your own code for checking if bottom of the page is reached. It will keep scrolling till footer is not present.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! In my case I used element.isDisplayed() as the condition.